# jQuery Autocomplete pass textbox value

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Trying to use [Ajax Autocomplete for jQuery, version 1.1.5](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/) and can get it to work by hard coding a value but that really doesn't seem to be why you would have autocomplete.

Below works but I really want to know how I make it so it just takes what's in the `q` textbox.   I tried `jQuery("q").val()` but that didn't work as well.

```
 <input name="q" type="text" maxlength="30" id="q" class="searchtextbox" />
  var ac = jQuery("#q").autocomplete({
            serviceUrl: 'autocomplete.ashx',
            minChars: 2,
            maxHeight: 400,
            width: 300,
            zIndex: 9999,
            deferRequestBy: 0, 
            // callback function:
            onSelect: function (value, data) { alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data)}
        });

        ac.enable();
        ac.setOptions({ params: { product_startsWith:'palm' } });
```

Comment: Unless you have a compelling reason otherwise, I would use the standard [jQueryUI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: yes, I am using jQueryUI currently but it's 199k vs 10k.   Looking to save on page load speed.

Comment: Makes sense... when you say it works when you hardcode, you mean the search term or the results?

Comment: @user, use the CDN as the file will more than likely already be cached on the users page.. so its 10k vs 0k :) http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js